# Issues with generating random images only twice from a list in Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm working on a memory game in Python tkinter and have come across an issue: In my function, choose_images, I'm trying to randomly generate 16 images from a list of 8 images, each image should appear twice. When I flip the cards, I see that some images show up more than twice. In addition, when I flip a card and then flip the card under it or above it, the two cards I flipped are always matching, meaning there is an issue with choose_images. Does anybody have any ideas of how to fix it?
My code:

```
from tkinter import *
from random import choice

screen = Tk()
screen.title("Disney Princesses Memory Game")
width = screen.winfo_screenwidth()
height = screen.winfo_screenheight()
screen.geometry("%dx%d" % (width, height))
screen.configure(bg="#e0bce5")

title = Label(screen, text="Memory Game", font=("David", 50, "underline", "bold"), bg="#e0bce5")
title.place(x=400, y=20)
rules = Label(screen, text="Single click to flip the first card, double click to flip the second card",
              font=("David", 30, "bold"), bg="#e0bce5")
rules.place(x=100, y=100)

images_list = [
    PhotoImage(file="images/aurora.png"),
    PhotoImage(file="images/belle.png"),
    PhotoImage(file="images/cinderella.png"),
    PhotoImage(file="images/jasmine.png"),
    PhotoImage(file="images/mulan.png"),
    PhotoImage(file="images/rapunzel.png"),
    PhotoImage(file="images/snow white.png"),
    PhotoImage(file="images/tiana.png")
]

buttons_list = []
chosen_images = []
flipped = []
num_list = []
card = PhotoImage(file="images/card.png")
count = 0
no_press = False


def choose_images():
    for num in range(16):
        chosen_image = choice(images_list)

        if chosen_images.count(chosen_image) > 2:
            chosen_images.remove(chosen_image)
        else:
            chosen_images.append(chosen_image)


def replace_card(c, d):
    global flipped, count, no_press

    if no_press is True:
        return

    count += 1

    if count > 2:
        count = 0
        no_press = True
        sleep_secs()
    else:
        buttons_list[c][d].configure(image=chosen_images[d])
        flipped.append(buttons_list[c][d])

    print(count)
    print(no_press)


def reset():
    global card, no_press
    for element in flipped:
        element.configure(image=card)
    flipped.clear()
    no_press = False


def sleep_secs():
    global no_press
    screen.after(2000, reset)


choose_images()
x = 100
y = 250
for i in range(2):
    buttons_list.append([])
    for j in range(8):
        a = Button(screen, image=card, command=lambda i=i, j=j: replace_card(i, j))
        x += 100
        a.place(x=x, y=y)
        buttons_list[i].append(a)
    y += 100
    x = 100

screen.mainloop()
```

Thank you so much to Henry and PCM for all the help! I truly appreciate it!
Updated code:

```
from tkinter import *
from random import shuffle

screen = Tk()
screen.title("Disney Princesses Memory Game")
width = screen.winfo_screenwidth()
height = screen.winfo_screenheight()
screen.geometry("%dx%d" % (width, height))
screen.configure(bg="#e0bce5")

title = Label(screen, text="Memory Game", font=("David", 50, "underline", "bold"), bg="#e0bce5")
title.place(x=400, y=20)
rules = Label(screen, text="Single click to flip the first card, double click to flip the second card",
              font=("David", 30, "bold"), bg="#e0bce5")
rules.place(x=100, y=100)

images_list = [
    PhotoImage(file="images/aurora.png"),
    PhotoImage(file="images/belle.png"),
    PhotoImage(file="images/cinderella.png"),
    PhotoImage(file="images/jasmine.png"),
    PhotoImage(file="images/mulan.png"),
    PhotoImage(file="images/rapunzel.png"),
    PhotoImage(file="images/snow white.png"),
    PhotoImage(file="images/tiana.png")
]

buttons_list = []
chosen_images = []
flipped = []
num_list = []
card = PhotoImage(file="images/card.png")
count = 0
no_press = False
turn = 0


def choose_images():
    while len(chosen_images) < 16:
        duplicate = images_list.copy()
        images_list.extend(duplicate)

        shuffle(images_list)
        for i2 in images_list:
            chosen_images.append(i2)


def turns():
    global turn
    turn += 1

    if turn % 2 == 0:
        turn_label.configure(text="Player 1's turn")
    else:
        turn_label.configure(text="Player 2's turn")


def replace_card(c, d):
    global flipped, count, no_press

    if no_press is True:
        return

    count += 1

    if count > 2:
        count = 0
        no_press = True
        sleep_secs()
    else:
        buttons_list[c][d].configure(image=chosen_images[(c*7)+d])
        flipped.append(buttons_list[c][d])


def reset():
    global card, no_press
    for element in flipped:
        element.configure(image=card)
    flipped.clear()
    no_press = False
    turns()


def sleep_secs():
    global no_press
    screen.after(2000, reset)


choose_images()

turn_label = Label(screen, text="Player 1's turn!", font=("David", 20), fg="red", bg="#e0bce5")
turn_label.place(x=520, y=180)
x = 100
y = 250
for i in range(2):
    buttons_list.append([])
    for j in range(8):
        a = Button(screen, image=card, command=lambda i=i, j=j: replace_card(i, j))
        x += 100
        a.place(x=x, y=y)
        buttons_list[i].append(a)
    y += 100
    x = 100

screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: You can try  to store the images in a list, shuffle the list and then make two images of each image

Comment: I tried using shuffle, but I was experiencing issues with it. Can you please demonstrate how to do what you recommended with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with `choose_images` is that the list is often less than 16 items long. This is because when you do the count check, you remove the card but don't try to add another one. Therefore the list is often less than 16 items. To fix this, replace the for loop with a while loop like this:

```
def choose_images():
    while len(chosen_images) < 16:
        chosen_image = choice(images_list)
        ...
```

This will make sure the list is always 16 items long, but there is still the problem that the top row is the same as the bottom row. This problem is caused in the `replace_card` function.
When you flip a card you change the image at the row/column of the card:

```
buttons_list[c][d].configure(image=chosen_images[d])
```

The problem with this line is that `chosen_images[d]` does not take into account the row number, so the top row will always be the same as the bottom row. To fix this, change `chosen_images[d]` to `chosen_images[(c*7)+d]`. When `c` is 0 (the first row), it will look at the first 8  (0-7) items in the list, then when `c` is 1 (the second row) it will look at items 8-15. Now it works as expected.

**EDIT** To stop images appearing more than twice, change the while loop to this:

```
while len(chosen_images) < 16:
        chosen_image = choice(images_list)

        if chosen_images.count(chosen_image) != 2:
            chosen_images.append(chosen_image)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You are so helpful! My only remaining issue is that some images show up more than twice. I'd be more than happy if you'd help me fix it

Comment: @Roni Edited it for you :)

Comment: But be aware of while loops, if the program gets bigger, then the while loop will mess your mainloop. It is better not to use while loops

Comment: @PCM It is perfectly fine to use a while loop. This one has a defined end condition and does not affect the rest of the program.

Comment: It is fine to use here though.

Comment: Thank you so much, PCM and Henry! You both got upvotes from me! You two significantly helped me!

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2):

1. Do not use `choice()`, use `shuffle()` - `from random import shuffle`
2. Change the logic so that you get the random cards

So for this, change this function -

```
def choose_images():
    duplicate = images_list.copy()
    images_list.extend(duplicate)
    
    
    shuffle(images_list)
    for i in images_list:
        chosen_images.append(i)
```

Comment: This can be simplified:  `chosen_images = images_list * 2; shuffle( chosen_images )`